# System Requirements for to host the wcf service in iis?

Tags: wcf

i am developing the wcf services in .net framework 4.0.for to host the service in server what are the minimum requirements of the system i.e minimum iis version etc.

what are the minimum requirements the system should have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF is part of the .NET Framework as of 3.0.  I would assume that any Windows system that can run .NET 3.0 should be able to run WCF.  Having said that, a little googling provides the following information:

For minimum requirements, I would say (based on experience and some googling):

Windows XP SP2/Windows Server 2003 R2/SP1
IIS 5.1

[WCF System Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733890.aspx)

However, with versions of IIS prior to version 7.0 - the absence of WAS will prevent you from using any of the non-HTTP bindings.  This could be a significant limitation, depending on what bindings you intend the service to use.

[Hosting in Internet Information Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734710.aspx)